# Graphical issues in a Fedora 29 box with KDE and XRDP for connectivity

Tags: linux, remote-desktop, fedora, kde

When connecting through XRDP on a KDE desktop, system settings is giving me black screens. E.g., in sidebar view there are two black boxes separated by a white separator in the middle. Changing the configuration to icon/tree view seems to allow me to see the tree; however, many screens, e.g., Workspace/Desktop Behavior/Workspace, show a black box on the right side. Image below.

If I go to this server directly through vSphere I do not have any graphical issues. System Settings is also the only place I've found this. I cannot determine if the problem is XRDP at this point.

[image: Tree View Image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is an issue with XRDP on the system. I disabled XRDP and went through and configured TigerVNC-Server (not an easy process). After connecting via VNC I was able to see everything with no issues. At this point I do not know what the problem is with XRDP, however I don't suggest its use on Fedora 29.